# Dealing with index out of bounds in SWIFT in tableview cell

Tags: swift

Language : Swift , REALM, Working with tableview cells to display user entries.

I have a problem where I cannot figure out how to display images in a table view cell where each cell has different number of images coming in and the images itself are optional when the user saves their entry.

here is my problem - When I create a new image view in my stack view as you see in the code, to display the second image in the list, I am getting the error that *the index path is out of bounds*. Also, I cannot unwrap the journalAspects.inPictures[0].realmToThumbNailImage() because I get an error saying that it is not optional.

How do I go about solving this problem of showing different number of images in different cells with out crashing the app.

I have 3 user entries in my app

- 1st one has text, date and no images
- 2nd one has text, date and 1 image
- 3rd one has text, date and 2 images

here is what I want to see in my table view cell

- first cell with just text and date
- second cell with text, date and 1 image
- third cell with text, date and 2 images

Thank you very much and your input is highly appreciated.

here is my code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let displayCell = journalAspectTableViewDispay.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstAddCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstAddTableViewCell

    if let journalAspects = RealmEntries?[indexPath.row] {

        //MARK: Text display

        displayCell.journalTextDisplayLabel.text = journalAspects.realmText

        let pictureImageView = UIImageView()

        pictureImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true

        pictureImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = truedisplayCell.stackViewForImageShow.addArrangedSubview(pictureImageView)

        let secondpictureImageView = UIImageView()

        secondpictureImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true

        secondpictureImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true

        displayCell.stackViewForImageShow.addArrangedSubview(secondpictureImageView)

        if journalAspects.inPictures.count == 0  {
            return displayCell
        } else {
            let imagesComingOut = journalAspects.inPictures[0].realmToThumbNailImage()

             secondpictureImageView.image = imagesComingOut

            let secondimagesComingOut = journalAspects.inPictures[1].realmToThumbNailImage() -- App crashes

            pictureImageView.image = secondimagesComingOut -- App crashes
        }
    }
    return displayCell
}







Hi, Thank you for your feedback, It is working, But when I implement it, I am having a strange problem. As I add new entries, the number of rows in the section won't change, and weird things happen. At first as I run and compile the app from the Xcode, everything seems right. Entries with one image has one image, entries with no image has no image and entries with 2 has 2. But as I scroll up and down, suddenly entries with no image gets populated with some image. Even though, I have added a new entry, the number of rows will still return the same. For instance if I have 10 entries at the start by running the compiler on the Xcode, then I add the 11th entry, as I scroll, the table view adds the 11th entry as 10th and knocks out the first entry. No matter how many I add, they just knock one down and add another at the top making the number of rows I see as a constant number since it is compiled. If you have any idea as to why that is happening, Please let me know Thank you again.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that `inPictures` actually contains 2 images?  You check that there's greater than 0, but not > 1.  That can be the only reason for an `out of range` error in that line.  A safer way would be:

```
switch journalAspects.inPictures.count {
case 2:
  secondpictureImageView.image = journalAspects.inPictures[0].realmToThumbNailImage()
  pictureImageView.image = journalAspects.inPictures[1].realmToThumbNailImage()
case 1: 
  pictureImageView.image = journalAspects.inPictures[1].realmToThumbNailImage()
  // or maybe the other one - hard to tell as you've mixed up sequencing
default: break
}
return displayCell
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your feedback, It is working, But when I implement it, I am having a strange problem. As I add new entries, the number of rows in the section won't change, and weird things happen. At first as I run and compile the app from the Xcode, everything seems right.

Comment: Entries with one image has one image, entries with no image has no image and entries with 2 has 2. But as I scroll up and down, suddenly entries with no image gets populated with some image. Even though, I have added a new entry, the number of rows will still return the same. For instance if I have 10 entries at the start by running the compiler on the Xcode, then I add the 11th entry, as I scroll, the table view adds the 11th entry as 10th and knocks out the first entry.

Comment: No matter how many I add, they just knock one down and add another at the top making the number of rows I see as a constant number since it is compiled. If you have any idea as to why that is happening, Please let me know Thank you again.

Comment: My guess would be a problem with ether the scope of variables that feed the table rows or an error in the logic in your datasource methods.  If you can't work it out, post another question with your tableView methods.  Tag me in a comment and I'll have a look later today if you want.